# Finding out what features of regular expressions are supported by mod_rewrite in Apache 1.3?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there a particular regular expression engine that is used by mod_rewrite on Apache 1.3?

I want to know so I can get a list of supported and non-supported features.

Answer (score 1):

For 1.3, it [looks like POSIX](http://louisville.edu/docs/apache/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule):

> Pattern can be (for Apache 1.1.x a System V8 and for Apache 1.2.x a POSIX) regular expression which gets applied to the current URL.

(I guess we were supposed to assume that meant 1.2 *and up*.)

For current versions, again [from the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex):

> mod_rewrite uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expression vocabulary. In this document, we do not attempt to provide a detailed reference to regular expressions.

From there, they provide some basics but mostly point you at Perl's regex docs for full information.